# AWS Elasticache SDK doesn't work for Redis ElastiCache

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-elasticache

I want to dynamically configure my API servers depending on the name of the "cluster".

So I'm using `AmazonElastiCacheClient` to discover the clusters name and need to extract the endpoint of the one that has a specific name.

The problem is that I can find it but there doesn't seem to be a way to get an endpoint.

`foundCluster.getCacheNodes()` returns an empty list, even if there is 1 Redis instance appearing in the AWS console, in-sync and running.

`foundCluster.getConfigurationEndpoint()` returns `null`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

DescribeCacheClustersRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

Answer (score 0):

I am making a guess:

AWS Elastic Cache with redis currenlty supports only single node clusers (so no auto discovery etc). I am not sure this is due this. Memcached based cluster is different.

"At this time, ElastiCache supports single-node Redis cache clusters." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheNode.Redis.html